# Not able to open port between windows 10 and locally hosted Ubuntu VM created on Hyper-v

Tags: windows-10, docker, hyper-v, telnet

This started when I was trying to use docker swarm join from the ubuntu vm (created using hyper-v) to my windows 10 docker engine. I am using the default port 2377. I keep getting connection refused error.

Now I am just trying to telnet over port 2377 from ubuntu vm to windows 10 or from windows to ubuntu and it is failing on both ways. while telnet is working fine on port 80.

I added inbound and outbound rules for both protocols udp and tcp on windows 10, and used the command "ufw allow 2377/tcp" on the ubuntu vm and also opened the port for both tcp and udp. Still it is not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody comes here.
after some analysis I discovered that there is a problem in docker engine itself. The port is not open.
Because I tried creating a simple app that listens on port 2377, and I ran it on the windows 10 machine then I was able to connect to it from the VM.
Also after running the swarm mode, I run the command "netstat -ab" on windows 10, and I can't see port 2377 listed.
I opened a topic on docker forums but no one has responded yet.
https://forums.docker.com/t/swarm-mode-is-not-working-on-windows-10/72761